# Updating after data binding does not update content in UI

Tags: vaadin7

Sorry, but I must have a mental lapsus right now, because I don't see where the problem is, and should be trivial. I've prepared a simple scenario where I bind a field to a bean property using the BeanFieldGroup, and when I click the Change and Reset buttons, the model is set with the correct values, but the textfield in the UI is not being updated.
I'm using Vaadin4Spring, but should not be the issue.

```
import com.vaadin.data.fieldgroup.BeanFieldGroup;
import com.vaadin.navigator.View;
import com.vaadin.navigator.ViewChangeListener;
import com.vaadin.spring.annotation.SpringView;
import com.vaadin.ui.Button;
import com.vaadin.ui.Notification;
import com.vaadin.ui.TextField;
import com.vaadin.ui.VerticalLayout;

import java.io.Serializable;

@SpringView(name = "test")
public class TestView extends VerticalLayout implements View {

    private TextField txtTest = new TextField("Test");
    private Button btnChange = new Button("Click!");
    private Button btnReset = new Button("Reset");

    private TestBean testBean = new TestBean();

    public TestView() {
        txtTest.setImmediate(true);

        addComponent(txtTest);
        addComponent(btnChange);
        addComponent(btnReset);

        BeanFieldGroup<TestBean> binder = new BeanFieldGroup<>(TestBean.class);
        binder.setItemDataSource(testBean);
        binder.setBuffered(false);
        binder.bind(txtTest, "text");

        initComponents();
    }

    private void initComponents() {
        btnChange.addClickListener(new Button.ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void buttonClick(Button.ClickEvent event) {
                testBean.setText("Hello world!");
            }
        });

        btnReset.addClickListener(new Button.ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void buttonClick(Button.ClickEvent event) {
                testBean.setText("");
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void enter(ViewChangeListener.ViewChangeEvent event) {
        Notification.show("Test");
    }

    public class TestBean implements Serializable {

        private String text;

        public TestBean() {
            text = "";
        }

        public String getText() {
            return text;
        }

        public void setText(String text) {
            this.text = text;
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling a bean setter directly and because Java doesn't provide any way to listen that kind of changes, the Vaadin property (or a TextField) doesn't know that the value has been changed. If you change the value through a Vaadin property by saying

```
binder.getItemDataSource().getItemProperty("text").setValue("new value");
```

then you see "new value" on the `TextField`, and because buffering is disabled, `testBean.getText()` also returns "new value".

Comment: Thanks @Henri, Marko already advised me about this. My immediate question comes about needing to have this text based property names. Isn't there a less error prone way to bind and modify values?

Comment: I've been used to use Pectin with GWT to avoid all this kind of things. Isn't there something the like in Vaadin?

Comment: @frandevel You could for example add a code generator to your project that generates constants from getters/and setters. When getters and setters are removed or renamed then you get compile time errors because the code generator doesn't generate used constants any more.

Answer (score 2):

The closest thing I have found is `binder.discard()`, which forces all bound fields to re-read its value from the bean. Yes, it still has to be called manually, but is still far less painful than `getItemDataSource().getItemProperty(...).setValue(...)`. If there are any concerns with this brute-force approach then of course one can call `Field.discard()` directly on the fields that should be affected.